# Missing folder in explorer

Tags: windows

The 'Users' folder on one of my clients SERVERS is mysteriously missing from its parent folder.

(I DO have hidden AND system folders shown, I have disabled and re-enabled this)

The folder is shared and can be accessed directly and DOES appear in DIR but does not appear in the folder listing in explorer

My guess is that the folder object is corrupt somehow, I am unsure of how to fix this.

Comment: Ouch. Too bad it's a) on a server and b) so far up the folder hierarchy. I would probably just format the partition and reinstall if that happened on a desktop, but that's probably not an option in this situation. It will be interesting to see what people come up with.

Comment: I assume you've run a `chkdsk -r`? if you type in a path within the users folder into explorer, does it come up or error out? have you checked the recycle bin to confirm it was not deleted?

Comment: I have not done any sort of scanning as of yet, the drive is a raid mirror and im hoping not to have to take the server down or the files offline. I can do anything I want with the folder from the command line AND I can manually type in the folder path to the explorer path area and access it, it just does not show up in the parent folder

Comment: Is there a hidden file named desktop.ini into the Users folder? If so, try to delete it.

Comment: Spot on, it was the desktop.ini in the folder, post as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If the output of the command:

```
attrib "C:\Users"
```

contains S or H in the first column, you will need to unset the relevant flag:

```
attrib -S "C:\Users"
```

or

```
attrib -H "C:\Users"
```

Whilst I hate "might be a virus" answers as much as the next person, a good starting point might be to run [rootkit revealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx) from Microsoft. That will at least give you a clue as to whether it's a configuration issue or the folder is genuinely (typically maliciously) invisible to Windows Explorer.

If you can bring up a powershell prompt, the output of the following command may also be informative:

```
get-acl "c:\users"  | Format-List
```

Comment: I had hidden and system folders shown, but ill check the attributes, ill let you know what I find on the other suggestions as well

Comment: The folder only has the r attribute set, this is an sbs2003 server so it does not have powershell by default, I will work on getting that downloaded and installed to look at the other listing, in the meantime ill look at the visual acl

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that "file scan" rights aren't enabled, at least for the account you're using.  You can just bring up the folder properties and see if "List Files" is unchecked, i.e. on a Win7 system it looks like this image; on a server, it might say "File Scan" instead.

[image: Rights to file scan]

Or it may say "List Folder / Read Data" like the below (ignore the red circling!):

[image: other wording]
If you click Edit, you can change the assigned rights for the listed user(s) or group(s).

Another possibility is that "Traverse Folder" rights are not granted;  that is set in the same place.

Finally, with Access Based Enumeration, users will only see the folders to which they have rights;  is it possible that someone turned on ABE?

Comment: Running as administrator with all rights allowed on both the parent folder and the folder im trying to look at

Comment: But you still need to check the rights as shown, or via another method;  just because you're an administrator doesn't mean that you don't have an ACL mis-set or gone bad. i.e. even Administrators can hide files from themselves. You'll note the setting is for directory listings etc., and NOT for read or write of files.

Comment: I meant when I looked at the Security tab the administrator had all rights on both the folder in question and the parent.